Pandas 'rename'-function not working within jupyter notebook?
I have a pandas dataframe ('df3') which columns I would like to rename.It is a subset of another dataframe, and I'm working in a jupyter notebook.
Getting all infos from the dataframe structure:
df3.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 29 entries, 104 to 132
Data columns (total 15 columns):
 #   Column       Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------       --------------  ----- 
 0   Zählung in   28 non-null     object
 1   Unnamed: 17  29 non-null     object
 2   Unnamed: 18  29 non-null     object
 3   Unnamed: 19  29 non-null     object
 4   Unnamed: 20  29 non-null     object
 5   Unnamed: 21  29 non-null     object
 6   Unnamed: 40  29 non-null     object
 7   Unnamed: 41  29 non-null     object
 8   Unnamed: 42  29 non-null     object
 9   Unnamed: 43  28 non-null     object
 10  Unnamed: 44  28 non-null     object
 11  Unnamed: 63  29 non-null     object
 12  Unnamed: 64  29 non-null     object
 13  Unnamed: 65  29 non-null     object
 14  Unnamed: 66  28 non-null     object
dtypes: object(15)
memory usage: 3.5+ KB


The columns need to be renamed by their index, so I create a dict with the index as keys and the new names as values:
col_names= {0:'Zeit', 
            1:'ZU_PKW', 
            2: 'ZU_LKW1', 
            3: 'ZU_LKW2', 
            4: 'ZU_SV', 
            5: 'ZU_SV%', 
            6:'AB_PKW', 
            7: 'AB_LKW1', 
            8: 'AB_LKW2', 
            9: 'AB_SV', 
            10: 'AB_SV%',
            11:'ALL_PKW', 
            12: 'ALL_LKW1', 
            13: 'ALL_LKW2', 
            14: 'ALL_SV'
           }


I tried to rename the columns with all options using the 'rename'-function:
1. Create a new dataframe with renamed columns without using inplace=True
df4 = df3.rename(index=col_names)

Result: no error, but the columns are not renamed
2. Create a new dataframe with renamed columns by using inplace=True
df4 = df3.rename(index={col_names, inplace = True)

Result: Error: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
And the resulting df is None.
3. Change the dataframe directly by using inplace=True 
df3.rename(index={col_names, inplace = True)

Result: `Error: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame and the df3 stays unchanged.
4. Specifying also axis=1
df3.rename(index={col_names, inplace = True)

Returns TypeError: Cannot specify both 'axis' and any of 'index' or 'columns'
I feel I'm running out of options. What am I doing wrong? Could it have something to do with working in the jupyter notebook environment?

df3.rename(columns=col_names)

What if I wouldn't want to rename all column names? I have this type of task coming up more often.

hmmm, best way is change dictionary

btw, seems columns names are Unnamed: 17, not 1, so need change dictionary

I'm using the column index to rename, not the column name

Then use df.columns = [d.get(i) for i in range(len(df.columns))]

The referenced discussion doesn't help with my answer, please reopen it. I tried a lot of the options in it, and it doesn't give an answer why it the renaming isn't working (as far as I have seen it).

@jezrael But I have multiple dataframes, and they may differ in their column names (while) their position in the dataframe stays the same, so I need to use the index, not the column name.

I note you say, " Could it have something to do with working in the jupyter notebook environment?", and your tile emphasizes Jupyter. In the future, troubleshoot the answer yourself by running the code or a toy version in Python direct. You probably get an option to run a terminal where you select to launch a new Jupyter .ipynb file. If you instead select a terminal and type python at the command prompt, you can bring up a Python interpreter there. Then type in or paste code in there and run it. Or put the Python code in a text file and add an .py extenstion and in the terminal ...

 point python at it with something like python my_script.py. Make sure you saved the file where you see it match with what you get when you run pwd in the terminal outside of Python. These are the more traditional ways to run Python code and if you get the same result then it doesn't have anything to do with Jupyter and you should not be emphasizing Jupyter, just mention it in the post somewhere. (A lot of times you can do that consideration in your mind.) Instead you'd emphasize Pandas and Python. It will also help you with considering search terms when looking for help.

If need rename by index of columns set values in list comprehension:
df.columns = [col_names.get(i, i) for i in range(len(df.columns))]

Or:
df.columns = pd.Series(range(len(df.columns))).replace(col_names)

If need set first N values by values of dictionary:
df.columns = list(col_names.values())[:len(df.columns)]

But if really need rename need change columns names to RangeIndex first:
df = df.set_axis(range(len(df.columns)), axis=1).rename(columns=col_names)


Thank you, this worked! However, why is 'rename' not working as above?

@i.i.k. - Reason is columns names are not RangeIndex, so if want use rename by your dictionary first need set_axis
